# Check if all lines in a file are in the same format

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to wrote a little shell script that permit to check if all lines on a file has the same number of `;`

I have a file containing the following format :

```
$ cat filename.txt

34567890;098765456789;098765567;9876;9876;EXTG;687J;
4567800987987;09876789;9667876YH;9876;098765;098765;09876;
SLKL987H;09876LKJ;POIUYT;PÖIUYT;88765K;POIUYTY;LKJHGFDF;
TYUIO;09876LKJ;POIUYT;LKJHG;88765K;POIUYTY;OIUYT;
...
...
...
SDFGHJK;RTYUIO9876;4567890LKJHGFD;POIUYTRF56789;POIUY;POIUYT;9876;
```

I use the following command for determine of the number of `;` of each line :

```
awk -F';' 'NF{print (NF-1)}' filename.txt
```

I have the following output :

```
7
7
7
7
...
...
...
7
```

Because number of `;` on each line of this file is 7.

Now, I want to wrote a script that permit me to verify if all the lines in the file have 7 commas. If it's OK, it tells me that the file is correct. Otherwise, if there is a single line containing more than 7 commas, it tells me that the file is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than printing output, return a value.  eg

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1{count = NF} NF!=count{status=1}END{exit status}' filename.txt
```

If there are no lines or if all lines contain the same number of commas, this will return 0.  Otherwise, it returns 1 to indicate failure.

Comment: I suppose it can be simplified to `'NR==1{count = NF} NF != count { exit 1}'`

Comment: @William, I tested with your command. I tried to add others commas but when I execute your command I have not output

Comment: @William, Indeed, it would be better to have a return code if I have a line that has more commas. But have you tested this command ? I have not a output even when I add others commas on a same line.

Comment: Yes, I have tested. No, you will not get output.  After you run the command, examine the value of `$?`.  This is designed so that you can run it like `if awk ...; then echo 'All lines have the same number of columns'; else echo 'ERROR' >&2; fi`

Comment: I tested with the script. He sends me back a return code if there is more commas on a colonne. It's good.

But what I really want to do is be able to tell my program that if all the columns or one of colonmn exceed exactly 7 fields, the file is not in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of unique lines and verify that the count is 1.

```
if (($(awk -F';' 'NF{print (NF-1)}' filename.txt | uniq | wc -l) == 1)); then
    echo good
else
    echo bad
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the result through `sort -u | wc -l`. If all lines have the same number of fields, this will produce one line of output.

Alternatively, just look for a line in `awk` that doesn't have the same number of fields as the first line.

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1 {linecount=NF}
           linecount != NF { print "Bad line " $0; exit 1}
          ' filename.txt && echo "Good file"
```

You can also adapt the old trick used to output only the first of duplicate lines.

```
awk -F';' '{a[NF]=1}; length(a) > 1 {exit 1}' filename.txt
```

Each line updates the count of lines with that number of fields. Exit with status 1 as soon as `a` has more than one entry. Basically, `a` acts as a set of all field counts seen so far.

Comment: Doesn't work for me @chepner. I have not a output too

Comment: You don't need output; the exit status tells you if your file is good or not. If you want output, you can test the exit status: `if awk ...; then echo "Good file"; else echo "Bad file"; fi`.

Comment: On my post, I wrote : `I want to wrote a script that permit me to verify if all the lines in the file have 7 commas. If it's OK, it tells me that the file is correct. Otherwise, if there is a single line containing more than 7 commas, it tells me that the file is not correct.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the information you have given me, I ended up doing the following. And it works for me.

```
nbCol=`awk -F';' '(NR==1){print NF;}' $1`
val=7
awk -F';' 'NR==1{count = NF} NF != count { exit 1}' $1
result=`echo $?`

if [ $result -eq 0  ] && [ $nbCol -eq $val ];then
echo "Good Format"
else
echo "Bad Format"
fi
```